# Raw SELECT (without FROM) of most recent 7 days to current

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I want to get the query result (e.g. to populate table) of last 7 dates (without times). I know that we can select some scalars without FROM statement. So I ended up with following solution:

```
select DATEADD (DAY, 0, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-1, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-2, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-3, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-4, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-5, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
Union
select DATEADD (DAY,-6, CONVERT(date, GetDate()))
```

Please point me to better (and more elegant) solution if there is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`VALUES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), table value constructor, is a little more concise.

```
select dateadd(day, x.num, convert(date, getdate()))
from (
  values (0), (-1), (-2), (-3), (-4), (-5), (-6)
) x (num)
order by x.num;
```

Returns:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-11-18 |
| 2021-11-19 |
| 2021-11-20 |
| 2021-11-21 |
| 2021-11-22 |
| 2021-11-23 |
| 2021-11-24 |

Comment: OMG it works) Thanks))

Comment: @YKPAIHELIb Be sure to ACCEPT the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also expand on the `values` table by using either a permanent *numbers/tally table* (always handy) or by generating an artibrary list of numbers from any suitable table, you can then create a list of dates for any period

```
select dateadd(day, n.v, convert(date, getdate()))
from (
  select top (30) v=-1 * Row_Number() over(order by (select 1))
    from master.dbo.spt_values
)n
order by n.v;
```